# "ever again", "never again" or "ever"

Tags: sentence-structure, british-english

> You won't able to see the light of day ever again.

> You won't able to see the light of day never again.

> You won't able to see the light of day ever.

Which one is correct?

Comment: None of them. They're all missing the syntactically required infinitive verb: *You won't **be** able to see the light of day...*

Answer (score 1):

> You won't able to see the light of day ever again.

> You won't able to see the light of day never again.

> You won't able to see the light of day ever.

*see the light of day* is defined as

> if an object sees the light of day, it is brought out of a place where it has been for a long time

and hence is a valid phrase.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/see-the-light-of-day

All the examples, however, miss out the copula *be*.  Further, example 2 has double-negative infringement, in its 'won't...never' construction.

With the insertion of *be*, examples 1 and 3 should be fine.

> You will not *be* able to see the light of day ever again.

> You will not *be* able to see the light of day ever.

Answer (score 0):

None of them are OK because they all omit the word *"be"* before *"able"* (thanks to @Kate Bunting for pointing that out). After adding the word *"be"* the sentences in the question can be understood as follows:

*"You won't* **be** *able to see the light of day ever again."* This is an OK phrasing. It suggests that they have previously seen the light of day, but are going to go somewhere (e.g., a deep dark dungeon) for the rest of their life.

*"You won't* **be** *able to see the light of day never again."* The two negatives (i.e., *"won't"* and *"never"*) in this clash and lead to a non-sensical statement. However, I have heard some people mixing their negatives when talking and so this might be said by some people and mean the same as the first phrase.

*"You won't* **be** *able to see the light of day ever."*. This is OK, but seems clumsy or an unusual phrasing. Perhaps adding a comma to give *"... of day, ever"* would work. The *"ever"* then being used to emphasise the preceding part. But this would depend on other sentances to set the scene more clearly.

*"You won't* **be** *ever be able to see the light of day."*. Not stated in the question, but this (using *"ever"*) may be a better variation of the third option.

Comment: It isn't OK, because it omits the word _be_ (You won't be able).